# GCC/MinGW problems with GSL

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, gsl

I'm attempting to compile a C-program using MinGW on Windows 7. The program relies on the CBLAS-library of GSL, so in short I'm (trying to) run this command in the terminal (cmd):

```
gcc MyProgram.c -o MyProgram.exe -O3 -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

This results in a long series of error messages of the form:

```
undefined reference to '_imp____infinity'
```

and

```
undefined reference to '_impure_ptr'
```

from various GSL-functions. I.e.:

```
/gsl-1.9/specfunc/trig.c:335: undefined reference to '_imp____infinity'
```

which seems to relate to the function OVERFLOW_ERROR in GSL.

I compiled GSL from source using MSYS (and prefix'ing configure with the path to MinGW), but it seems to me that the linking to the GSL-libraries is not the issue - i.e. the functions appears to be located correctly.

For the record, I can remove the CBLAS-based parts of the program (making the program somewhat useless) and successfully compile the program using:

```
gcc MyProgram.c -o MyProgram.exe -O3 -lm
```

where I've placed the appropriate directories in PATH.

I am quite puzzled by this unexpected error, as it seems that linking to GSL messes up the links to the fundamental C-libraries? Furthermore, the program compiles fine on Ubuntu 15.04 (with the GSL-flags).

Comment: I don't understand how you are getting references to `__infinity`, or to `_impure_ptr`, into any MinGW build; is it possible that you have header pool contamination by Linux (or similar) header files? From inspection of MinGW's `<math.h>`, I see that `MSVCRT.DLL`'s equivalent for `infinity` is `_INF`; MSDN does not document `impure_ptr`, and I know of no `MSVCRT.DLL` equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Shuffling around the compiler-flags has no effect (as pointed out by @KeithMarshall). I'll have another look at my MinGW setup in order to properly answer the second question and get back to you - but as I recall, most of it is pretty much just out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *definitely* should *not* be incurring references to either `__infinity`, (which is what would translate to a DLL import reference of `_imp____infinity`), or to `_impure_ptr`, within a *clean* MinGW build of GSL. For the record, I just downloaded `gsl-latest.tar.gz`, unpacked it and did, (using a Linux hosted gcc-4.8.2 mingw32-cross-compiler):

```
$ mkdir gsl-1.16/build
$ cd gsl-1.16/build
$ ../configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
...
$ make
$ make prefix=`pwd`/staged install
```

This creates the following content in `staged/lib`:

```
$ ls -R staged/lib
staged/lib:
libgsl.a      libgslcblas.a  libgslcblas.dll.a  libgslcblas.la
libgsl.dll.a  libgsl.la      pkgconfig

staged/lib/pkgconfig:
gsl.pc
```

and subsequently running `nm` on the generated libraries, confirms the absence of such references:

```
$ nm -A staged/lib/*.a | grep infinity
$ nm -A staged/lib/*.a | grep impure_ptr
```

I also performed a STFW on `undefined reference to _impure_ptr`, having failed to find any MSDN reference; the most useful hits were to a cygwin ML thread, suggesting that such references are generated when the user improperly adds cygwin's header path to the MinGW compiler's `-I` search path at build time ... i.e. deliberate contamination of the header pool.

Comment: I'm guessing, you are absolutely correct. I re-installed the newest version of GSL using your suggested commands, which seems to have solved the issue.

I'm still somewhat puzzled as to how I managed to introduce Linux-like headers into the header pool, but it seems your diagnosis is accurate.

Thank you very much for your insights!